# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=e^x$ for $x<0$

Tags: limits

We know that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=e^x$$ if $$x\geq0.$$
An equality suggested for this problem by the book states that
$$\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=1+(-1)^n\left(\frac{x^n}{n!} \right)^2,  (x<0)$$

If we place $x=-y, y>0$ and then take a limit of both sides for $n \to \infty$, we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+...+\frac{y^n}{n!}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[1+(-1)^n\left(\frac{y^n}{n!} \right)^2 \right],x<0,y>0 $$
Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+...+\frac{y^n}{n!}\right)=e^y$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}=0$, we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\cdot e^y=1$$
But $y=-x$, so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\cdot e^{-x}=1$$
which implies that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=e^x,x<0$$
But the problem is that the suggested equality seems to be false for all $n>2$ (though I checked for a few first n's only). So I'm looking for another way to prove that $\lim... = e^x$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a correct form for the same product of series polynomials, we get

$$ \begin{align*}
P_n(x) &= \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\right) \\
P_n(x) &= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \frac{x^{i+j}}{(i!)(j!)} \end{align*} $$

Considering the square of integer points $0 \leq i,j \leq n$, we can take the diagonals where $i+j$ is a constant $k$. These diagonal sets increase in count with $0 \leq k \leq n$, and then decrease in count with $n \leq k \leq 2n$.

$$ P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sum_{j=k-n}^n (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} $$

To get the sums with $k > n$ compatible with the sums with $k \leq n$, we can consider the $k > n$ case when summed over the larger set $0 \leq j \leq k$ minus the sums over $0 \leq j < k-n$ and $n < j \leq k$:

$$ P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{k-n-1}(-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} + \sum_{j=n+1}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!}\right) $$

But when $k>0$, by the binomial expansion,

$$ \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j 1^{k-j} {k \choose j} \frac{x^k}{k!} = (-1+1)^k \frac{x^k}{k!} = 0 $$

So the first sum is just $1$ from the $k=0$ term:

$$ P_n(x) = 1 - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{k-n-1}(-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!} + \sum_{j=n+1}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!}\right) $$

Changing index variable with $j = k-m$ in the sum with $0 \leq j \leq k-n-1$ gives $n+1 \leq m \leq k$, and then the two sums differ only by the sign term:

$$ \begin{align*}
P_n(x) &= 1 - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \left( \sum_{m=n+1}^{k}(-1)^{k-m} \frac{x^k}{m!(k-m)!} + \sum_{j=n+1}^k (-1)^j \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!}\right) \\
P_n(x) &= 1 - \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sum_{j=n+1}^k (-1)^j ((-1)^k+1) \frac{x^k}{(k-j)!j!}
\end{align*} $$

Since $(-1)^k+1$ is $0$ when $k$ is odd and $2$ when $k$ is even, we can take just the terms where $k=2\ell$:

$$ P_n(x) = 1 - 2 \cdot \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil}^n \sum_{j=n+1}^{2\ell} (-1)^j \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(2\ell-j)!j!} $$

That's about as much as it will simplify, but now we can find some simpler inequalities which will still be strong enough for this proof. Ignoring terms with odd $j$ gives a result not larger than $P_n(x)$, and ignoring terms with even $j$ gives a result not smaller than $P_n(x)$:

$$ -2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \sum_{i=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^{\ell}\frac{x^{2\ell}}{(2\ell-2i)!(2i)!} \leq P_n(x) - 1 \leq 2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \sum_{i=\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}^{\ell-1} \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(2\ell-2i-1)!(2i+1)!} $$

Since a row of Pascal's triangle is largest at its center,

$$ \frac{1}{(2\ell-j)!j!} = \frac{1}{(2\ell)!} {2\ell \choose j} \leq \frac{1}{(2\ell)!} {2\ell \choose \ell} = \frac{1}{(\ell !)^2} $$

$$ \begin{align*}
-2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \sum_{i=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^{\ell}\frac{x^{2\ell}}{(\ell!)^2} &\leq P_n(x)-1 \leq 2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \sum_{i=\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}^{\ell-1} \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(\ell!)^2} \\
-2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \left(\ell-\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil + 1\right) \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(l!)^2} &\leq P_n(x)-1 \leq 2 \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n \left(\ell-\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\right) \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(\ell!)^2} \\
-\sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n (2\ell-n+1) \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(l!)^2} &\leq P_n(x)-1 \leq \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n (2\ell-n+1) \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(\ell!)^2}
\end{align*} $$

$$ |P_n(x)-1| = \left|\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\right) -1\right| \leq \sum_{\ell=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil}^n (2\ell-n+1) \frac{x^{2\ell}}{(\ell!)^2} $$

What's left is to show that $P_n(x)$ converges to $1$ for every negative $x$. Think you can take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $g_n(x):=1+(-1)^n(\frac{x^n}{n!})^2-(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{x^i}{i!})(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-x)^i}{i!})$.

What can you say about $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(x)$?

Comment: Well, if I'm not wrong, then $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{-x^i}{i!} =\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \left(\frac{x^i}{i!} \right)^2$$ which means that $$g_n(x)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i \left(\frac{x^i}{i!} \right)^2$$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x)=1+\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \left( \frac{x^i}{i!}\right)^2$$

Comment: Not much, if one of the summations is unknown. (The claimed fact about the product of sums is indeed false.)

Comment: Then I'm not sure what should I do with the hint

Comment: Yeah, i misunderstood what the OP's issue was.  @Cakeice, can you prove the limit by providing convergence of the sum for all $x$, and proving that the function defined by the power series is equivalent to its derivative (any power series is differentiable everywhere it converges), then solving the ODE $f'=f, f(0)=1$?